# Indesign: what are the blue outlines around objects and how can they be hidden / toggled on or off?

Tags: adobe-indesign, shortcuts

How do you hide the "blue outlines" around objects in InDesign?

Every new object I create on an InDesign board is surrounded by a thin blue outline. I don't know what these are called as I'm a newbie so I am unable to locate instructions on how to toggle their display. I am sure there must be a way to toggle this outline off and on.

I am aware of the following keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> to display/hide the document grid
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to display/hide guides

But I can't figure out how to remove the blue outlines around objects and I can't see an option under *View → Grids & Guides* that seems applicable.

Comment: I rejected the suggested edit of replacing "blue outlines" with "selection marks" because, as a new user of InDesign, I had no idea that this is what they were called. I believe similarly inexperienced users will likely also be searching using terms such as "blue outlines".

Comment: I would be interested in knowing why this question has been down-voted.

Comment: Understandable, just thought I'd try to clarify since the blue outlines would only be on Layer 1 in a new document by default.

Comment: Still don't understand why this question is being down-voted. I spent AGES searching Google for how to do this. As a novice InDesign user, not knowing the terminology of the application was my problem and all I could do was search for help using a *description* of my problem. How is one to know they are called "frame edges"? I'm sure I'm not the only novice user out there...

Comment: FYI: They are only _blue_ because your default layer color is _blue_. This can be changed to a number of other colors by double-clicking the layer name (Layer 1), in which case your _blue outlines_ will change to another color. So _blue outlines_ does not describe the concept correctly, they are called _frame edges_ as others have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Lucian. Actually, I answered my own question and discovered they were called "frame edges". Others gave names like "selection marks". I would imagine that for other newbie InDesign users, they would also have the default color setup in place.

Comment: Thank you! I also am a new user and searched for blue lines. This really helped me.

Comment: Classic - just got the "Famous Question" (viewed 10,000 times) gold badge for this. I think using "blue outlines" was the right call. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "blue outlines" are known as 'Frame Edges' and their visibility can be toggled using either:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Main menu → View → Extras → Show/Hide Frame Edges

Answer (score 6):

A nice simple way to do this is to toggle between Normal View and Preview Mode by hitting <kbd>W</kbd> on the keyboard. This will also hide the bleeds, margins, and slug guides in your document. Just be careful not to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> as this is the Close Document shortcut.